# Make very detailed SVG map of world country borders and administrative objects

Tags: mapping, svg, mercator

I need very detailed map for my project, in Mercator projection.
I tried to find downloadable resources, even not free, but all that I have found is in very bad resolution.
I need as much detailed borders as it possible (I need small islands and etc.)

Here is image of high res SVG map I have done, but it had mistakes(made it joining Google Maps screenshots by mouse and drawing on them in SVG redactor)[image] so I stopped doing it.

Comment: You could have a look at https://99boundaries.com/

Comment: Question is better suited for [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) since this is a data question and not a geospatial software or method question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher-resolution data is often available through local government (state/provincial or national) mapping departments. Departments / groups that often publish data include

- Data groups (open data, geography portals, etc.)
- Survey
- Transportation
- Mining / Geology
- Census

One public free source that is worth looking at is https://www.naturalearthdata.com/